# How do I split an array into a bunch of strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, rmagick

This method accepts a list of URLs:

```
Magick::ImageList.new("img1url", "img2url", "img3url")
```

I have this string `"url1, url2, url3"`.

How can I feed the above method my list as separate arguments? I tried:

```
urls = urls.split(',')
Magick::ImageList.new(urls) # fails. It produces an array.

# fails. It produces "'img1url','img2url'".
# The comma is part of the string, but it should split method arguments.
urls = urls.split(',').join("','")
Magick::ImageList.new(urls)
```

Comment: try `Magick::ImageList.new(*urls)`

Comment: -1. What is `urls`? What is the relation between `"url1, url2, url3"` and `"img1url", "img2url", "img3url"`?

Comment: @sawa who cares? The question is clear enough. I doubt anyone else is having difficulty connecting the dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` can expand the array to arguments:

```
urls = urls.split(', ')
Magick::ImageList.new(*urls)
```

Comment: `Magick::ImageMagickError: no data returned 'http://7.jpg,8.jpg,9.jpg'` -- I cut short the urls. If I pass the images in individually, they work. The comma is still appearing inside the string...

Comment: @dee: Oh, take out the space in `', '` then. Your sample string gave me the impression that they were separated by a space and a comma.